# Log4j2 and Flume on Jetty Server

Tags: java, maven, jetty, flume, log4j2

I am trying to do centralised logging of a distributed system using Log4J2 and Flume-ng. One of the servers in the system runs Jetty which I am using to do web services (servlets) for the system. When I include the Maven dependencies for Log4J2 an Flume-ng in this project it breaks Jetty and it will not start up/bind properly. If I remove the dependency in the list below (log4j-flume-ng) then Jetty will run as normal giving me the following output:

```
2012-10-08 16:36:33.457::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2012-10-08 16:36:34.285 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=gs-adhoc1-test.jrs-software.co.uk/10.1.1.161:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2012-10-08 16:36:34.290 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@31ac05
2012-10-08 16:36:34.272::INFO:  jetty-7.0.0.pre5
2012-10-08 16:36:34.322::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:5000
```

But with that dependency in, it come up as (just the Memcached output):

```
2012-10-08 16:36:34.285 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=gs-adhoc1-test.jrs-software.co.uk/10.1.1.161:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2012-10-08 16:36:34.290 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@31ac05
```

The dependencys in Maven POM are as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>       
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
        <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>couchdb4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchdb4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0-i386-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
        <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-flume-ng</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-alpha2</version>       
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't know how to begin solving this. I have managed to get Flume working with my other servers no problem but it appears that Jetty will have none of it. Can someone offer any advice to get this working?

Comment: that version of jetty was before our move to eclipse, try 7.6.7 - http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/

Comment: Did you implement this solution in your distributed system? I'm also working on something very similar and I'd be interested to hear your experience and share ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently used jetty-6.1.26 with log4j2 in my project. It seems that you miss log4j2-jcl to bridge commons-logging from other packages, instead of excluding it. I could not start my project without it. You will need to define **commons-logging.properties** to use Log4j2 implementation and make sure it appears first in your class path.

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

log4j2 is still beta2 and has a known bug with commons-logging, I've found that it is fixed in beta3 but not sure when it will be released.